# What is the port range for Minecraft LAN worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I want to invite my friends over the internet into my LAN world in Minecraft, I need to set my router to forward the port specified by Minecraft. As Mincraft picks a different port each time I open my world over LAN, I have to edit my router settings every time I want to start a multiplayer LAN session over the internet. Instead, I would like to set the router to the range of port numbers that Minecraft picks from.

**What is the range of ports that Minecraft uses for LAN worlds?**

So far, after four sessions, I have had ports between 49525 and 50852. I play the Java edition, if that makes any difference.

---

*Alternatively:*

The port range must be coded into the Minecraft code. What file(s) would I look at to find it?

Comment: I mostly meet server with port 25565, but I think Minecraft reads ports of the host and finding the "minecraft" one

Comment: Technically speaking, a LAN world can be hosted on *any* port. [All you need to do is broadcast your server the same way a LAN game does](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/lanbroadcaster.5320/).

Answer (score 2):

Since minecraft 1.13 there is a command to change the port

`/publish [<port>]` e.g. `/publish 9000` to set the port to 9000.

you can read more at [minecraft wiki - command publish](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/publish)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround for a similar situation.

First of all, I wanted to access the server over the internet and I wanted my friends to join again over the internet (all of us were located outside the LAN).
2nd I am running a lot of other services on the LAN and it is unacceptable for me to open port, moreover a range of ports.

I came across the service called [Tunnel In](https://tunnelin.com/) - which is a **tunneling provider** and **cloud port forwarder**. The freemium plan allowed me:

1. **Remotely access** to my server, start Minecraft and learn about the port number
2. **Create a secure tunnel** and expose the Minecraft server through firewall **without port forwarding** and without compromising the security of LAN

Here is a nice post on [how to allow Minecraft through firewall](https://tunnelin.com/blog/how-to-allow-minecraft-through-firewall).